# How does this 今できなくても、できるとき work?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing with a japanese penfriend on italki, and I've got a few problems with what she has written me in japanese ^^

For context: Amongst other things, I've written her that I've changed my profession. I successfully finished my studies to become a teacher, but I've changed into the IT-sector because in my country (germany, bavaria) there is no need for teachers on schools anymore for the subjects I've studied.

Now, I haven't written her this background information and as far as I can understand, she tries to convince to go for it :D The problem is, as I said, that I don't understand everything she has written me.

So first, the full text:

> 仕事を始めるとき、最初の何年かはとても大変ですね。でも嫌でも続ける事は、何か自分に意味があります。そういうふうに、日本では言います。だから、本当に自分のしたい事が今できなくても、できるときがくるので、そのときまで粘ってください！かな？？？

The sentence in question:

> だから、本当に自分のしたい事が今できなくても、できるときがくるので、そのときまで粘ってください！

Before I write down my translation, I must say that this part confuses me quite a lot and I wonder whether I understood the preceding parts correctly at all.

I actually wonder here whether she tells me that I should go for becoming a teacher, even though it might not be "the job I want to do" because "the time will come when I can (=when it became the job I want to do?), or if she tells me to "keep going (in my current job), because the time will come" where I can do this job :D

Here is my translation:

> "Because of that, while now not doing the thing you yourself want to do, because the time where I do comes, please do your best until then."

One last thing:

> かな???

What does it express in the way it is standing here?^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 仕事を始めるとき、最初の何年かはとても大変ですね。でも嫌でも続ける事は、何か自分に意味があります。

Already the meaning of this seems explained in other threads for you.

> そういうふうに、日本では言います。

So, she says this is kind of aphorism in Japan. And, now she is paraphrasing in the aphorism way.

> だから、本当に自分のしたい事が今できなくても、できるときがくるので、そのときまで粘ってください！かな？？？

These are equivalent phrases as the former.

本当に自分のしたい事が今できなくても... 粘ってやる ≅ 嫌でも続ける事。

その時がくる　 ≅　何か自分に意味がある。

"Therefore, even if you can not do what you really want to do now, the time definitely comes. So, slog through it until then!" Okay???

かな？？？　implies she wonders if you could take what she said as an advice.